# Connect mobile and desktop Air apps via Wifi Hotspot

Tags: android, air, wifi, wifi-direct

I'm attempting to connect air apps via a wifi hotspot that is setup on the Windows laptop, using something like this:

```
netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=tests key=tests123

netsh wlan start hostednetwork
```

I can connect my Android device to this network.

Usually I connect devices over Wifi using something like this
[Adobe Air - How to detect LAN servers (listening to a specific port)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21112329/adobe-air-how-to-detect-lan-servers-listening-to-a-specific-port/21159308?noredirect=1#comment46503910_21159308)

I can connect the devices and the Android device is receiving data and sending data to the correct IP, however the Desktop Air app that is running the WiFi hotspot is not receiving data. Any clues why that might be?

Answer (score -1):

Turned off Windows Firewall which was blocking port

Comment: Care to elaborate a bit more?  Did you turn of Windows Firewall or did you add a rule?  If so what port? What protocol?  Duplex?

Comment: Turned off Windows Firewall. Hard to add a rule with a debug file. Why so many questions? Do you really care? Are you going to suggest a better approach?

Comment: If you must know the SO System had already flagged your answer as **low quality**.  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer - Maybe I've got the same problem but reading your answer doesn't tell me anything until reading your recent comment.   .  Also, please curb your rudeness.  To me turning off the firewall is a poor solution so there is that.

Comment: Awesome. Please suggest a way with a better solution - like how do you configure the air app to request permission to use the port? What's the protocol you speak of and what is a duplex?  Give a useful answer and I'll hand you the points.

Comment: OK that sounds like a completely different question that I'll have to deal with when the time comes. The answer to why my apps weren't communicating is Windows Firewall.  A useful answer would be how to configure the app to request Firewall permissions, I don't yet know how do that. When I get to fixing that, I'll look for help - I'm sure your'll be very happy to oblige!

Comment: All I'm saying is that you probably could have opened a particular port in Windows Firewall **manually** rather than closing it completely.  That would have been awesome since peeps generally like to keep firewalls open.   But  yes totally agree, to do it programatically would be awesome too!